# In netsuite how to write a curl script for selected records that does not exists in saved search.?

Tags: javascript, curl, netsuite

In this problem i need a curl script where i can check all my records by email id's of customer,So for this stuff i have text file source from where i can see customer email id's and then implement in script

Answer (score 0):

Need more details on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

The closest that you can achieve this is thru the RESTLET API of Netsuite. Pre-requisite is to know how REST works and suitescript API.

Comment: first of all thx for answering....:)
you know in this i need a email or unique id from my text file because email is a unique thing in all columns so i want to use it first.And i need a suitescript for this which will search customer in netsuite by email id.